# Do I need to reset protection before calling free

Tags: c, linux, memory, posix, mprotect

I allocated some large chunks of memory through `malloc` and `aligned_alloc`, and then I setup a fence to a region inside the memory with size of one page size, using `mprotect`:

```
void *buf = malloc(128 * PAGE_SIZE);
int ret = mprotect(buf, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_NONE);
```

Now I'm done with the memory and is calling `free(buf);` to release it, my questions is do I need to reset `mprotect` before calling `free`, like this:

```
ret = mprotect(buf, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE);
free(buf);
```

Or should I just do `free`? I read that glibc will sometimes reuse some of the previously allocated memory, so if this region of memory is returned to later `malloc`, will accessing it cause problems(since it's `PROT_NONE`)?

Answer (score 1):

Malloc allocated from the heap does not necessarily request the memory from the system. Likewise free does not necessarily return the memory to the system.

For what you are doing you should use mmap munmap which always goes to the system. If you use mfree there is no need to call mprotect beforehand.

Comment: What is this mfree are you talking about? Do you mean munmap?

Comment: Sorry, I do mean munmap. Corrected now. My bad

Comment: What about malloc? Is it wrong to use mprotect on malloc'ed memory? Or is it implementation dependent? or even undefined behavior?

Comment: Yes, don't use mprotect on malloced memory. Malloc is a heap allocator that manages memory that may be less than an OS page. mprotect needs a whole page since access attributes only have page granuality.

Answer (score 1):

On top of @doron 's answer, I digged a little more because I was specifically working on Linux. According [posix standard of `mprotect`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mprotect.html):

> The behavior of this function is unspecified if the mapping was not established by a call to mmap().

While on [Linux](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect), it is a bit different:

> On Linux it is always permissible to call mprotect() on any address in a process's address space (except for the kernel vsyscall area). In particular it can be used to change existing code mappings to be writable.

That means it is indeed allowed to call `mprotect` on `malloc`'ed memory regions, but `free` will not reset it as there is no way to know the old protection flags, so I have to reset the flags before calling `free`.

In fact, this is exactly the problem I met, when the program runs for a while, it randomly crashes in `malloc`, that is because `malloc` is writing it's housekeeping data into the previously allocated memory and that memory was set to `PROT_NONE` by an earlier `mprotect`, after I set the memory to writable before calling `free`, the program never crash again.

That's being said, this is only on Linux, to write portable program, one should use `mprotect` only on `mmap`'ed memory.